# Strange gdb 7.9 boost on Yosemite 10.10.13

Tags: macos, gdb

I just updated my system to `osx 10.10.13`, and reinstalled the `gdb7.9`. I can use it with some simple debug action. But when i try to "`r`" in `gdb`, it shows

```
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/corecrypto/corecrypto-233.1.2~26/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libcorecrypto_static.a"
warning: `/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.20.2~10/Objects/coretls.build/coretls.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/system_coretls_vers.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.20.2~10/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libcoretls_ciphersuites.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.20.2~10/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libcoretls_handshake.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.20.2~10/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libcoretls_record.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/coreTLS/coreTLS-35.20.2~10/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libcoretls_stream_parser.a"
```

It seems strange, could you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you codesign gdb, similar to the instructions [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin)? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Yes, I have already done it. But the problem has not been solved. Thank you for your replying all the same.

Answer (score 2):

This happens only in Yosemite and only for GDB after 7.8, so installing GDB 7.7 solves the problem, as described in [this issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/issues/483). You can fix it by removing your GDB, and install GDB 7.7 with [this formula](https://gist.github.com/ymyzk/10ad2b74af9235eddb2c), i.e., with command

```
brew install https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ymyzk/10ad2b74af9235eddb2c/raw/9d0b9734ea01f9753a5f54dd221acd99ee7e53e8/gdb.rb
```

Note:

- I am not sure whether this is necessary, but I tapped the formula to prevent it from updating to latest GDB 7.10.
- I assume you already [codesigned](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin) it.